# Octopress installation issues at> rake generate

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, octopress

Having some trouble installing Octopress. I'm not too sure whats going on, but I'd love to understand this error message and debug it.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
➜  octoblog git:(source) ✗ sudo bundle exec rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0020 p:-17526087697918 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 TOP
c:0019 p:---- s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 CFUNC  :require
c:0018 p:0025 s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 TOP    /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:2
c:0017 p:---- s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 FINISH
c:0016 p:---- s:0061 b:0061 l:000060 d:000060 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0011 s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 TOP    /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:2
c:0014 p:---- s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 CFUNC  :require
c:0012 p:0039 s:0049 b:0049 l:000048 d:000048 TOP    /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments.rb:1
c:0011 p:---- s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0138 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 TOP    /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll.rb:27
c:0008 p:---- s:0039 b:0039 l:000038 d:000038 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0037 b:0037 l:000036 d:000036 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0072 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 TOP    /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:20
c:0005 p:---- s:0014 b:0014 l:000013 d:000013 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0167 s:0008 b:0008 l:000298 d:000098 EVAL   /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/jekyll:23
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000298 d:000298 TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:20:in `require'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll.rb:27:in `require'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:2:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/jekyll

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/rbconfig.rb
    5 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/pathname.bundle
   10 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   11 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   12 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/etc.bundle
   13 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb
   14 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
   15 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   16 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
   17 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
   18 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   19 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
   20 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
   21 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
   22 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
   23 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   24 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   25 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   26 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/version.rb
   27 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb
   28 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/settings.rb
   29 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
   30 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest.bundle
   31 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
   32 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/sha1.bundle
   33 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
   34 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb
   35 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
   36 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
   37 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   38 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source.rb
   39 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
   40 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
   41 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
   42 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
   43 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
   44 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
   45 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
   46 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
   47 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
   48 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
   49 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/errors.rb
   50 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/text.rb
   51 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
   52 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
   53 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/strscan.bundle
   54 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
   55 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
   56 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
   57 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
   58 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb
   59 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb
   60 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
   61 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb
   62 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
   63 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb
   64 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
   65 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
   66 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
   67 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb
   68 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb
   69 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb
   70 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/date_core.bundle
   71 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
   72 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
   73 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
   74 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/syntax_error.rb
   75 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/psych.bundle
   76 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/stringio.bundle
   77 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb
   78 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb
   79 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/document.rb
   80 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
   81 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
   82 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
   83 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/alias.rb
   84 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes.rb
   85 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/streaming.rb
   86 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
   87 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
   88 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
   89 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
   90 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
   91 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
   92 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
   93 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
   94 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors.rb
   95 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/handler.rb
   96 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/tree_builder.rb
   97 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/parser.rb
   98 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/omap.rb
   99 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/set.rb
  100 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/coder.rb
  101 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/core_ext.rb
  102 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb
  103 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/stream.rb
  104 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
  105 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
  106 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/stream.rb
  107 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
  108 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb
  109 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb
  110 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/English.rb
  111 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/drop.rb
  112 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/extensions.rb
  113 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/errors.rb
  114 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/strainer.rb
  115 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/context.rb
  116 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tag.rb
  117 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/block.rb
  118 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/document.rb
  119 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/variable.rb
  120 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/file_system.rb
  121 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/template.rb
  122 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/htmltags.rb
  123 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
  124 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
  125 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
  126 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
  127 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb
  128 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/condition.rb
  129 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/module_ex.rb
  130 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/assign.rb
  131 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/capture.rb
  132 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/case.rb
  133 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/comment.rb
  134 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/cycle.rb
  135 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/decrement.rb
  136 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb
  137 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb
  138 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/ifchanged.rb
  139 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/include.rb
  140 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/increment.rb
  141 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/raw.rb
  142 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/tags/unless.rb
  143 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid.rb
  144 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parseexception.rb
  145 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/formatters/default.rb
  146 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/formatters/pretty.rb
  147 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/node.rb
  148 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/child.rb
  149 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parent.rb
  150 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xmltokens.rb
  151 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/namespace.rb
  152 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/encoding.rb
  153 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/source.rb
  154 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/entity.rb
  155 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/attlistdecl.rb
  156 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/doctype.rb
  157 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/text.rb
  158 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/attribute.rb
  159 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/cdata.rb
  160 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/functions.rb
  161 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/syncenumerator.rb
  162 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/xpathparser.rb
  163 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath_parser.rb
  164 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb
  165 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb
  166 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xmldecl.rb
  167 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/comment.rb
  168 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/instruction.rb
  169 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/rexml.rb
  170 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/output.rb
  171 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/undefinednamespaceexception.rb
  172 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb
  173 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/streamparser.rb
  174 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/validation/validationexception.rb
  175 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb
  176 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb
  177 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/structures.rb
  178 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/structures_inspect.rb
  179 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/defaults.rb
  180 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/helpers.rb
  181 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/parse_doc.rb
  182 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/string_utils.rb
  183 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/linesource.rb
  184 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/type_detection.rb
  185 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/html_helper.rb
  186 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/parse_block.rb
  187 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/charsource.rb
  188 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/parse_span_better.rb
  189 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/rubypants.rb
  190 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/input/extensions.rb
  191 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/attributes.rb
  192 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/structures_iterators.rb
  193 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/errors_management.rb
  194 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/toc.rb
  195 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/ext/div.rb
  196 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/version.rb
  197 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb
  198 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_latex.rb
  199 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_latex_strings.rb
  200 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_latex_entities.rb
  201 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_markdown.rb
  202 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/s5/to_s5.rb
  203 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/s5/fancy.rb
  204 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_s.rb
  205 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/maruku.rb
  206 /Users/lkbogdonoff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to debug this you would have to look more into posix_spawn_ext. Based on the following link it sounds like this is an issue caused by Lion's compiler being LLVM and not GCC by default: https://gist.github.com/imathis/1104557